# How can I design a coffee cup with a specific handle?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm designing a coffee espresso cup.
I can manage it except for the handle.
What is the more precise process to design the handle (like the one in the photo)?
Thank you[image]

Comment: Maybe this video can help you my friend ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBtDix7xGOg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your image as reference, create a cylinder, create some vertical edge loops:

[image]

Extrude 3 faces:

[image]

Extrude one face along the shape of the handle:

[image]

At the end select the 2 opposite faces and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, bevel some edges, move some vertices until it looks like your cup:

[image]